# inline-block goes under floated div

Tags: css-float, css

I'm trying to style my headings with `display:inline-block;` but i've a problem with a behavior of the property.

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Tu2GU/

See the titles, when a title has a long text, the heading goes under the floated div. I want the heading to break and then display 2 lines (or more) and stay on the left of the floated div, not under it.

Can't find anything helping, thanks !

---

edit : i updated the jsfiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/Tu2GU/13/ (removed % width for the floated div)

I don't want to have 2 divs side by side, the floated div on the right is meant to be right there, like a page summary giving link inside the page.

Also, heading are under the floated div (in html code) not over.

Comment: You should include your relevant code in the question itself

Comment: By the time I finished adjusting percentages this post already had answers Btw Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Tu2GU/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the right list uses a percent width, you can set a `max-width` with a percent width

```
h2 {
    ... Your original CSS ...
    max-width:calc(75% - 40px); /* 40px comes from horizontal padding */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu2GU/14/)

I'd recommend using a class to apply to each header instead of using the same max-width on each `h1`, `h2`, etc, but that's just personal preference

If the width of the right floated div is set, use `calc(100% - 440px)` or whatever the left horizontal padding + right width is

Comment: I updated the question. The floated div is not meant to have a % width, my bad.

Comment: Yes, but you use % width for the floated div, i edited it for a pixel width. So the issue is still there.

Comment: Ah right, i didn't knew this calc function, That's exactly what i'm looking for, thank you. Need to find some hacks for IE though (http://caniuse.com/calc).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `float: left;` container using the CSS below:

```
.lfloat {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
 }
```

You just have to wrap your text in a new div:

```
<div class="lfloat">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu2GU/15/)**

This will contain the content to the left and keep your sidebar to the right.

Note: You must clear your floats with `clear: both;`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try floating the elements on the left instead of using inline-block?

```
* {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.rfloat {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background: #9C3;
    color: #111;
}
h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    background: #06C;
    color: #FFF;
}
h2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 5%;
    background: #F33;
    color: #FFF;
    width:65%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4Grv/

Comment: I updated the question, floated div shouldn't be with % width, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

updated your Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tu2GU/12/
Main thing was a wrapping `div` around your h1 and p tag alongside of `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top`
Is this what you needed?

Comment: I updated the question, floated div shouldn't be with % width, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. You can float the heading to the left so that it will slide up - you will have to set a width, though.

```
h2 { 
    float: left; 
    width: 80%;
}
```

Another option would be to set a max width. Since inline-block elements are technically block level, you can supply a width without breaking anything. You could try this:

```
h2 {
    max-width: 80%
}
```

Yet another option would be to make the element inline. This will let the browser determine the best fit for the header.

```
h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

This will make the header wrap around the list and you may get the results you want. This method will make `height` and `width` parameters not work, so you will have to substitute those for `line-height` and `padding`

Comment: I updated the question, floated div shouldn't have % width. I considered using `display: inline` but the render is quite different from `inline-block`.